# Visual Studio Property Page Inherit Macros From Other Projects

Tags: visual-studio, macros, inheritance

So I am having a very difficult time finding a solution to this problem.  Is there any way that I can inherit macros from another project.  For example, for the post build I would like to use the macro for the RemoteMachine address that is located in one project in all the other projects.  I was thinking something like (ProjectContainingMacro.$RemoteMachine) ... does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: the reason that I need this is instead of manaul putting the Remote Machines address in each one of the post builds command line for each project, i can possibly just put it in one and the rest possibly inherit from that one... if it is possible.  This is just for convience when switiching from on machine to the other and having 20 plus projects.

Answer (score 3):

A possible fix to this is that you can add user defined macros to a property sheet and inherit the property sheet.  Thus now I can pass the new user defined macros in the command lines for the post builds and there is only one file to change if I change machines which is the properties sheet itself.

Comment: still looking for a better way though... anyone?

Comment: yes but you can add the property sheet to your revision control system (alongside your project and solution file), so when you check out from another machine you will keep the post build macros.